# Using python and boto3 for aws to describe-spot-fleet-instances?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

What would be equivalent to this aws cli command using python3 and boto3?

```
aws ec2 describe-spot-fleet-instances --spot-fleet-request-id xxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
```

I looked in boto3 documentation [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_fleets) and there doesn't seem to be one or perhaps I'm not understanding the commands fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is , **describe_spot_fleet_instances(**kwargs)**

Request syntax :

```
response = client.describe_spot_fleet_instances(
    DryRun=True|False,
    MaxResults=123,
    NextToken='string',
    SpotFleetRequestId='string'
)
```

**Parameters**

- DryRun (boolean)

  -- Checks whether you have the required permissions for the action, without actually making the request, and provides an error response. If you have the required permissions, the error response is DryRunOperation . Otherwise, it is UnauthorizedOperation .
- MaxResults (integer) --

  The maximum number of results to return in a single call. Specify a value between 1 and 1000. The default value is 1000. To retrieve the remaining results, make another call with the returned NextToken value.
- NextToken (string) --

  The token for the next set of results.
- SpotFleetRequestId (string) --

  [REQUIRED]

  The ID of the Spot Fleet request.

**Here is how you will make low-level client object**

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
```